# Why does localeconv() return empty string ("") for thousands_sep in Italian (it_IT) on Linux?

Tags: linux, locale

Why does localeconv() return empty string ("") for thousands_sep in Italian (it_IT) on Linux? It works fine on Mac OS X.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main () {
   struct lconv * lc;

   printf("locale %s\n", setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "it_IT"));
   lc = localeconv();
   printf("Thousands Sep: %s\n",lc->thousands_sep);
   printf("Decimal Point = %s\n", lc->decimal_point);

   printf("locale %s\n", setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_US"));
   lc = localeconv();
   printf("Thousands Sep: %s\n",lc->thousands_sep);
   printf("Decimal Point = %s\n", lc->decimal_point);

   return 0;
}
```

Mac OS X 10.9.1:

```
locale it_IT
Thousands Sep: . 
Decimal Point = ,
locale en_US
Thousands Sep: ,
Decimal Point = .
```

Ubuntu 12.10:

```
locale it_IT
Thousands Sep: 
Decimal Point = ,
locale en_US
Thousands Sep: ,
Decimal Point = .
```

CentOS 6.5:

```
locale it_IT
Thousands Sep: 
Decimal Point = ,
locale en_US
Thousands Sep: ,
Decimal Point = .
```

Comment: Wonder if `thousands_sep` was put in another category like `LC_MONETARY` under Ubuntu?  Does the same inconsistency occur with `LC_ALL` vs. `LC_NUMERIC`?  See [somewhat similar bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/langpack-locales/+bug/546581)

Comment: I see the same problem with LC_ALL and LC_NUMERIC. Looks like it could be a [bug in glibc](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10797).